# Invalid literal error for pad_sequences from Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I have a pretty long list of lists. They are in different lengths so I'd like to pad them using the pad_sequences method from Keras.

Here is a small sample from my list.

```
[['1052510314,561817251071255315530393310539,17], [18431041015251031392510310310559110712301031391839,1052510314,561817251071255315530393310539], [17,1818431041015251033925103103121061210310559110712301031010]]
```

Items in the inner list are pretty long, however, the total length of the main list is 8252.

I tried to pad it like this;

```
# pad documents to a max length of 4 words
max_length = 1000
paddedX = pad_sequences(X, maxlen=max_length, padding='post', dtype="int64")
print(paddedX)
```

and I'm getting this error;

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1052510314,561817251071255315530393310539,17,18431041015251031392510310310559110712301031391839,1052510314,561817251071255315530393310539,17,1818431041015251033925103103121061210310559110712301031010
```

As far as I know, pad_sequences method uses int32 datatype by default. That may be causing the error. If so is there a way to use something like long dtype in C?

Note: The elements in the list are already one-hot encoded.

Comment: 1818431041015251033925103103121061210310559110712301031010 is far away from primitive data types, even far away from longs. I don´t know what you plan to do with that huge numbers, but if you use them as features, you should map them into integer space.

Comment: These are basically opcode sequences from an APK and one-hot encoded every two strings using Dalvik. Each number is representing a method of an APK as encoded. I guess I may want to one-hot encode for the second time to map those into int32.  @Digital-Thinking